# A Simple Riddle

Tags: riddle

My hair may be coarse, but regardless keeps clean.
When in dust and decay, these strands create gleam.

Comment: My next riddle will be longer and hopefully harder

Comment: Will your next riddle be soon enough?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

is it

> a <s>mop</s> broom?
>  which has "coarse hairs" and keeps things clean, and makes previously dusty or dirty things gleam

Comment: You’re really close, I thought it was less obvious. I removed a red herring from the draft.

Comment: It could be a rot13(oebbz)?

Comment: QuantumTwinkle’s got it

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Toothbrush? Keeps teeth clean. Teeth sparkle as shown in advertisements.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer may have been given but a potential answer can be :

> Cleaning Brush.

As,

> They have have hairs too., that to of different type one of them maybe course as well. A brush is a common tool with bristles, wire or other filaments. It is used for cleaning, grooming hair, make up, painting, surface finishing and for many other purposes. It is one of the most basic and versatile tools in use today, and the average household may contain several dozen varieties.